# how to sort and display an arraylist based on points in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist

I have an array list named memberData that stores the memberID, memberName, memberPoint and some other member data. I want to sort all the members based on the memberPoint field.

Here is my code:

```
public void displayAllMembers()
    {
        int index = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("ALL MEMBERS");
        Console.WriteLine("No\t Member Name\t\t Member ID\t Member Point");
        memberData.Sort();
        foreach (object data in memberData)
        {
            tempMember = (Member)data;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t {1} {2}\t\t {3}\t\t {4}", index, tempMember.givenName, tempMember.surName, tempMember.memberID, tempMember.memberPoint);
            index++;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please provide more code (e.g. the definition of memberData) and be more specific about the problems you encountered (error messages, expected vs. observed behaviour, etc.). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

### Using LINQ

Instead of `Sort()` which only uses the internal `Equals` to compare objects in the list you simply can use LINQ for this:

```
var sortedByMemberPoint = memberData.OrderBy(m=>m.memberPoint);
```

This will sort your member data by the property provided in the `OrderBy` method. To sort descending use `OrderByDescending()` instead.

### Using IComparer

Alternatively you can implement your own comparer class to compare the member data (which is quite an overhead for your simple use case). That is recommended if you want to do more complex comparison.  You can have a look on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for a simple sample.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use LINQ functions for sorting depending on sorting directions like this:
To sort in ascending order:

```
memberData = memberData.OrderBy(m=>m.memberPoint);
```

To sort in descending order :

```
memberData = memberData.OrderByDescending(m=>m.memberPoint);
```

Comment: i tried to type the OrderBy() but errors generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    public class MemberData : IComparable<MemberData>
    {
        public static List<MemberData> memberData = new List<MemberData>();

        public string givenName {get;set;}
        public string surName {get;set;}
        public string memberID { get;set;}
        public string memberPoint { get; set; }

        public void displayAllMembers()
        {
            int index = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("ALL MEMBERS");
            Console.WriteLine("No\t Member Name\t\t Member ID\t Member Point");
            memberData.Sort();
            foreach (MemberData data in memberData)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t {1} {2}\t\t {3}\t\t {4}", index, data.givenName, data.surName, data.memberID, data.memberPoint);
                index++;
            }

        }
        public int CompareTo(MemberData other)
        {
            if (this.givenName != other.givenName) return this.givenName.CompareTo(other.givenName);

            if (this.surName != other.surName) return this.surName.CompareTo(other.surName);

            if (this.memberID != other.memberID) return this.memberID.CompareTo(other.memberID);

            return this.memberPoint.CompareTo(other.memberPoint);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @derape said, you can use also an **IComparer**, here you can have an example using that approach also

```
void Main()
{
    A[] a = new A[]
    {
        new A
        {
            Point = 10,
            Name="A1"
        },
        new A
        {
            Point=6, 
            Name="A2"
        }, 
        new A
        {
            Point=7, 
            Name="A3"
        }
    };

    Array.Sort(a, new AComparer());

    //at this point a has all element sorted
}

public class A
{
    public int Point { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}


public class AComparer : IComparer<A>
{
    public int Compare(A x, A y)
    {
        if(x.Point == y.Point)
            return 0;
        if(x.Point < y.Point)
            return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps